# Visual Studio project character set problem

Tags: visual-studio, encoding

I had a Visual Studio 2010 MVC 2 project with spanish characters in my views.

I converted the project to Telerik MVC 2 project and now I get weird characters in place of the special characters in my views during execution (they're shown ok in the aspx code in Visual Studio).

E.g.: I used to see this during execution:

[image: before conversion to telerik]

I now I see this:

[image: after conversion to telerik]

This only happens with the Master Page content.

In Visual Studio: where do I set the encoding used when saving/loading files? The Telerik conversion seems to have messed that up, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how did the Telerik conversion break that. But I've solved the problem this way:

1. Created a new master page named `Site2.Master`
2. Copied the content from `Site.Master` to `Site2.Master`
3. Deleted `Site.Master`
4. Renamed `Site2.Master` to `Site.Master`